# How to set default remote in git?

Tags: git, branch, git-pull

I have multiple remotes in my git repository. If I execute `git pull`, then it asks for the password of one of my colleagues.

How can I change the remote to `black`?

Comment: `git pull {originName}`? you could also move things around so that `origin` is yours.

Comment: @DanielA.White, I want to simply call `git pull` not `git pull black`

Comment: `origin` is the name of a remote (the one where the repo was cloned from). There is no way to have more than one `origin`.

Comment: @axiac, I see. I changed the question title accordingly.

Comment: Try `git config branch.<name>.remote black`. `name` is the branch you are on now.

Comment: @ElpieKay, thx! That worked

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no default remote, each branch can track a specific branch from a remote repo.

If you have created the branch using `git checkout -b <branch-name>` where `<branch-name>` is the name of a remote branch then the new branch tracks that branch (from whatever remote hosts it).

If you created the branch locally then used `git push --set-upstream <remote-name> <branch-name>` then the local branch `<branch-name>` tracks the remote branch `<remote-name>/<branch-name>`.

You can always use [`git branch --set-upstream-to`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch---set-upstream-toltupstreamgt) to change the remote branch that is tracked by the current branch or [`git branch --unset-upstream`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch---unset-upstream) to tell it to not track any remote branch.

Comment: how can I push/pull from a remote/branch that's not the upstream? In my case, I have my master branch on github, but I also have a bare repository on my network drive that has master. I've fetched everything from both and want to fast-forward master to the bare repository since that's the most up-to-date CURRENTLY... while leaving the upstream as is. Do I have to change the upstream twice or is there a shorter way to do that?

Comment: wait, I'm just being dumb. `git merge desktop/master`

Answer (score 48):

In addition to the response above that describes how to set the remote repository for an existing branch in your local copy, I felt it would be worthwhile to expand on this, by noting that **while a default remote *cannot* be setup for `git pull`, a default remote *can* be set for `git checkout` in your repository using the `checkout.defaultRemote` setting.**  This way, `git checkout some-branch`, `git push`, and `git pull` will all *Just Work™* the way you intended, without specifying or thinking about the remote name at all. Read on for a full explanation.

Note to OP: In my examples below I'm going to use the remote name `origin` instead of your specific remote named `black` because for most people, the default *origin* remote is the one you'd want to setup like this.  For your purposes though, just replace any instance of *origin* with *black*.

### Simplify your branch checkout process:

First, you'd type the following in the console:

```
git config checkout.defaultRemote origin
```

This command adds the following section to your repository's .git/config file:

```
[checkout]
     defaultRemote = origin
```

Now, with a default branch configured, each time you want to setup a new local copy of a remote branch that exists on the "origin" remote repository, you only need to type:

```
git checkout some-branch
```

And git will assume you actually meant:

```
git checkout --track origin/some-branch
```

Which can also be shortened to:

```
git checkout -u origin/some-branch
```

This is an amazing lifehack. It is a much smarter alternative method of setting up a local copy than the solution mentioned above with `git checkout -b some-branch` and is so very useful when you *actually know that the branch already exists* on one or more remotes.  Particularly, if you're working with multiple remotes and not using `defaultRemote`, you would need to type the long form `git checkout --track origin/branch-name` each time you checkout a branch, because git doesn't know from which remote it should track.  Save yourself a headache and just set this up always. (See final thoughts below for a suggested approach).

### Simplify your git push and git pull process:

As hinted at above, having your local branches auto-configured to track from the defaultRemote means that when you need to do a `git pull` while on some branch you checked out, git already knows exactly which remote to pull from. This is very, very helpful.

Note: if the local branch tracks one remote and *you want to pull code from a different remote*, or if the local branch is not setup to track a remote at all, then you can either:

- manually specify the correct remote to pull from:

  ```
    git pull <remote-name>
  ```

  This must be done each time you want to pull from the remote.
- fix the remote tracking branch permanently on a branch-by-branch basis using:

  ```
    git branch --set-upstream-to <remote-name/branch-name>
  ```

  OR

  ```
    git config branch.<branch-name>.remote <remote-name>
    git config branch.<branch-name>.merge refs/heads/<branch-name>
  ```

  This is a one-time change; all subsequent `git pull` commands should now pull from the remote/branch you specified.

### Caveats and implications:

For `git config checkout.defaultRemote origin` to be of any real benefit for a `git pull` command scenario, this command/configuration needs to be set up when you first start working on a project with multiple remotes, or as soon as you start adding additional remotes. The reason is because this configuration will only have an effect on branches you're going to check out **after** having set this configuration; it doesn't have any effect on existing branches. In which case, all existing local branches that don't already track from a specific remote will need to be modified separately to add the intended remote before a simple `git pull` will work.

### Final thoughts

If you find yourself hitting this issue often on various projects, a more comprehensive setting would be to work under the convention that the default remote should always be added as the "origin" remote in all your projects. You can then set this configuration globally with:

```
git config --global checkout.defaultRemote origin
```

Comment: Why does the config need to be setup immediately? What would happen if you set it up later?

Comment: Only that doing `git checkout some-branch` wont necessarily set it up with a remote, which means more commands later in your git process.

Answer (score 4):

To automate the process for this branch :

```
git config branch.<your-branch>.remote black
```